# Can't serialize collection of collections

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have this model of data:

```
    public abstract class AbstractCollection
    {

    }

    public abstract class TypedAbstractCollection<T1> : AbstractCollection
    {

    }

    public class MyCollection<T> : TypedAbstractCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly List<T> _valueList = new List<T>();

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _valueList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(T value)
        {
            _valueList.Add(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(MyCollection<string>))]
    public class Shallow : IEnumerable<AbstractCollection>
    {
        private readonly List<AbstractCollection> _listOfCollections = new List<AbstractCollection>(); 

        public IEnumerator<AbstractCollection> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _listOfCollections.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(AbstractCollection sample)
        {
            _listOfCollections.Add(sample);
        }
    }
```

I use IEnumerable in my collection with Add() function to automatically serialization it as collection, but when I try to serialization it in XML:

```
        Shallow shallow = new Shallow
        {
            new MyCollection<string>
            {
                "first",
                "second"
            }
        };

        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(shallow.GetType(), 
            new[] { typeof(OneWayMapper<string, string>) });

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, shallow);
        }
```

I've got the strange error without any needed information:

> The type 'MyCollection' may not be used in this context

But, if I will use instead of MyCollection class `MyItem<T>` with typed item value - there won't be any errors.
So it's ok with typed collections, abstract class and so on, but not with collection of collections.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I've tried to store MyCollections as 'public readonly List<AbstractCollection> ListOfCollections = new List<AbstractCollection>()' and use 'XmlArray', but it did't helped. I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

And I found a problem. To make it work we have to make AbstractCollection inherit of IEnumerable.
And it's very understandable.